# embedded Linux, UART & JTAG disabled, how to access system?

Tags: serial-communication, firmware-analysis, jtag

So i have this device running embedded Linux, UART and JTAG interfaces are disabled by software. The device creates a WiFi hotspot and i know the password. By entering the devices IP adress i can access its web interface. Apart from that it has a RS232 port to communicate with a SPS.

I need to download / copy some files from the device.

Any ideas?
TiA

Comment: What system? How do you know they are disabled by software? What about accessing the storage directly? If it has a working serial connection (RS232) try that. If present, maybe vulnerabilities in the web interface.